# $(document).click from two locations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I call an external js file. This js file already has a `(document).click` function. I want to have an `(document).click` within the main js.

external js:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

I do not use global variables. What's the best way to have `$(document).click` function in the external file and also to add an `$(document).click` function within the main js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have both.  As long as nobody stops propagation, both event handlers will run.

Do post the code if you still have any trouble.

Expanding the answer a bit:
There is in fact a way (the wrong way) to do click event handlers that supports only one at a time.  If you do:

```
element.onclick = function () {alert('a')};
```

And then

```
element.onclick = function () {alert('b')};
```

You will get only one alert (saying 'b').  Which is why you should never use that.  This is a remnant of a time when nobody knew what they were doing.  It's 2015, the less we talk about it the better.

Now, when you use the proper way of registering event handlers:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function () {alert('a')});
element.addEventListener('click', function () {alert('b')});
```

You'll get both alerts.

To clear up any confusion, it's worth mentioning that jQuery uses the same old `addEventListener` internally when you do `$(element).click(f)` or `$(element).on('click', f)` or however it works today.

Comment: With Javascript and the browser, never say never :P But it should be fine.  I'll expand my answer a bit, see if it helps.   About your "bind" comment, I'm not sure I understand.  It is very common to use `bind` in callbacks, but for different reasons.  Nothing to do with several callbacks interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

> You can add 'click' event on both the file,but the problem is, when
>   you click on that particular element both the handlers will fire on
>   the same time If i am not wrong, both handler will work differently
>   and should not fire at same time.
>
> Best way use Event trigger with different name spaces of events.

```
$(document).on('click.func1',function(){
    func1();
});
$(document).bind('click.func2',function(){
   doStuff2();
});
```

Then when you need to trigger you can choose order.

```
 $(document).trigger('click.func1').trigger('click.func2');
```

Or you can trigger both event on same time:

```
$(document).trigger('click');
```